# Why was my reopen flag on a CSS question I'd edited declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, reopen-closed

I recently voted to reopen [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40875080/621962) because it was, in my opinion, closed erroneously. Two people downvoted, three people offered completely incorrect (now deleted) answers, and five people voted to successfully place the question on hold. I believe that's because they were somehow unable to infer the issue or they mistakenly wrote it off as a duplicate *selector specificity* question.

Unfortunately, the question is actually about the counter-intuitive behavior of `!important` CSS styles inherited from ancestor elements. Now, the OP didn't know that... and neither did most of the people who read his question. So, I voted to reopen after revising it for clarity (although, I thought it was pretty clear to begin with).

With so many failures surrounding the reception and understanding of this question, I felt that maybe a moderator flag was warranted for reopening. However, I received a canned rejection:

> should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I'm a little perplexed. When am I supposed to engage a moderator if not when there's a community failing? From the help center:

> [image]

<strike>To be fair, the question has gained two more reopen votes; so, maybe there's hope that the review queue won't let it die over the weekend.</strike> Apparently it's dead already.

Comment: The question got pushed into the [reopen queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14467148) (see the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40875080/timeline)), where the consensus was 'Leave Closed'. A moderator isn't needed to reopen questions where the community can do it.

Comment: It shouldn't be reopened in its current state; the user has not provided the CSS code necessary to resolve the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you don't need the CSS given the HTML and the computed style information... but I will _synthesize_ the necessary CSS if that somehow satisfies you.

Comment: @canon And how do you know that it's representative of the OP's actual code?  A given symptom can almost always have any number of different causes.  If you just pick one, it's rather likely that you pick something different than the OP's actual problem.

Comment: @canon The problem with you syntesizing it is that it may be what the OP is doing, and it may not be.  If there were only one way to generate a given output with CSS, I don't think we'd have so many problems with CSS as a language.

Comment: Note that the question is actually a duplicate, so it can be closed for that reason...

Comment: I *think* it's a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6129304/215552, but they are slightly different...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well apparently we're just editing questions so that they ask what we want them to already, regardless of the OP's actual situation, so why let that stop us now.

Comment: @Servy [that does appear to be the case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338667/215552) ;)

Comment: @canon Yeah, that's why I didn't vote. One of the answers on that question answers with much the same info as yours, but is a much worse question overall.

Comment: @canon If you want to take what you feel is a sufficiently educated guess at an answer, that's one thing, but to edit the question to change it from what it was asking to what your guess is that it's asking, then that's *very* different.  If you want to ask your own question, then ask your own question, don't edit your question into a question someone else is asking.

Comment: @canon And yet you did it anyway...trying or not.  That you're confident doesn't change any of my points, nor does it change SO's policy on what type of content is appropriate to edit into someone else's question.  It is up to the OP to provide the information that their question is missing, not for you to guess it.

Comment: @canon While extrapolating some of the details of information not shown; details that may or may not be different from the OP's situation in ways that are relevant to an answer.  It's not like you were just moving content verbatim from a comment into the question.

Comment: @canon I'm not enough of an expert in the area to know.  If I was, I would have already rolled it back.  Can you prove that there is no possible implementation that could ever result in a different problem being the root cause?

Comment: @canon In my experience, virtually every single time anyone has ever been entirely confident that they knew exactly what the OP's actual code was, despite it not being provided, there were other possible explanations for the behavior.  People can often enough guess the most likely cause, but there are almost always less likely possible explanations, and when those situations *do* come up all of the confusion of people making incorrect assumptions always turns the question into a giant mess, very often removing any shot of a correct answer.

Comment: @canon Well, some of it anyway.

Comment: @canon You think.

Comment: @canon So there's no possible edit that anyone could conceivably make to the question, without removing any of the code the OP added themself, that could ever result in your answer being incorrect?  No other possible implementation, or omitted code, that could result in the rule being overridden for a different reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Seconds after I posted this, you re-wrote the entire question to include an actual, runnable test case, thus fulfilling the requirements for a debugging question - I've responded by reopening. Leaving the answer below as an explanation for why your previous efforts were insufficient.*

---

Quoting [that help center list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), so I can add emphasis:

> 1. Leave a comment on the question itself calling for it to be reopened. **Be detailed: explain why the question shouldn't have been closed.** Be constructive: name-calling is as likely to drive folks away as it is win them to your cause. Remember, anyone on the site with at least 3,000 reputation points can vote to reopen a question - even if a moderator closed it.
> 2. Be sure that you've read the close notice and any comments on the question so you can address any concerns raised there. Addressing the concerns often means editing the post, which any user may do.
> 3. Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, **explain why it should be reopened.** There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.
> 4. If you have at least 3,000 reputation points, vote to reopen yourself.

Now, the first problem here is... This was your flag:

> Please reopen this question; it shouldn't be on hold. The question is clear and on-topic.

That's... Not very detailed. Your argument appears to be that the close reason doesn't apply, so let's quote the close reason too:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Let's see...

1. Question *is* seeking debugging help.
2. Question *does* include desired behavior (computed size 16px).
3. Question *does* include a specific problem (computed size 22px).
4. **Question DOES NOT INCLUDE CODE NECESSARY TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM.**

Here's the code in the question:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="stec">
    <p class="stec-layout-month-daycell-num">31</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's... Not enough to reproduce the problem.

Now... You might be able to synthesize a test case based on that screenshot, but so far no one has done so. Your edits - and your less-than-detailed justification for reopening in the flag - were insufficient.

There's another issue here too: suggestion #3 in the help center was sorta aimed at questions that *a moderator had closed*; this is hinted at by the "moderators do reconsider their decisions" bit, but not very explicit; I should probably edit that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I jumped on George's comment regarding the missing CSS and just added a stack-snippet. Now, the flag description wasn't very detailed because I hoped that the edits had made the question clear enough to stand on its own merit... and, failing that, a mod would see my comments, the edit history, etc. Another important lesson in expected perception, I guess. Thanks for the response (and reopening the question), Shog. The OP may never come back but others might.

Comment: And if they do, the question now provides an example of how to include a succinct test case. Something we could certainly use a lot more of.

Answer (score 2):

If you think a question should be reopened, then vote to reopen it.  If the community feels that it merits reopening, it can be reopened.  The community is more than capable of dealing with the situation, if the question does in fact merit reopening.  You should only be flagging for moderator attention when there is a problem that community moderation isn't able to solve.

Comment: @canon well that doesn't change how the system behaves. Diamond mods don't really get involved in stuff like that that the community can handle. :/

Comment: @canon there are things the community CANNOT handle. These are when you should flag for moderator attention. If it's a matter of "I'm right, the community is wrong", most of the time you'll have to convince people....

Comment: @canon to be fair at least **eight** different users voted to close or leave closed (5 to close + 3 in the queue) - the consensus seems to be that the question is indeed not that great...

Comment: @canon here, it seems like you are just disagreeing with the community. It's not a "fail to handle", it's a "people are disagreeing with you". You need to be convincing I guess...

Comment: @canon and imean i can guess it's frustrating when you are trying to make the site a better place and it feels as if the community who would benefit from your actions is fighting you. However... Trying to force the systemto work the way you want is never likely to produce a good outcome:/. But yeah I can definitely empathize with the frustration